# PHP throw error "Use of undefined constant" in xammp?

Tags: php, xampp

I have config.php:

```
<?php
  define("HASHID_KEY", "u827983983jisuuujmksskd");
?>
```

and function.php

```
<?php
 require("config.php");
 require_once 'hash.php';
 $GLOBALS['hashids'] = new Hashids\Hashids(HASHID_KEY);
?>
```

When I run it in localhost( I use XAMMP) I got error *"Notice: Use of undefined constant HASHID_KEY - assumed 'HASHID_KEY' "*. But if I'm deploy it to server VPS it's working normally.

How can I reslove it?

Comment: It sounds like it's loading the wrong `config.php` on localhost.

Comment: But why It's working on my vps?

Comment: Because it's finding the correct `config.php` there.

Comment: I try test by add   define("HASHID_KEY", "u827983983jisuuujmksskd") in function.php and it's warmning variable existed in config.php, it's meaning that it's finding correct config.php, so it's not loading wrong

Comment: Sorry, I have no other guesses.

Comment: ok,thank. No problem

Comment: try `require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');` - it has fixed issues like this for me before by putting the absolute path to the file